Can a value be assigned to links in HTML?
I am currently doing a project where we must recommend schools based on the answers chosen. The answers must take you to another webpage after each question and once done it should recommend schools based on your choices.
This is all being done currently on HTML on notepad++ as i am a beginner.
I want to know if there is a way to assign some kind of value or a way to track options picked so that the school recommended reflect the answers picked. I know that you can do it in js by assigning the answers numerical values but is that possible in HTML? if not, how could I go about this?
Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

    <title>Question 13</title>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:white;">

    <h1 style="font-family:fantasy;text-align:center;color:black;font-size:100px;"> Does the number    of enrolled students matter to you? </h1>

    <p style="font-family:monaco;text-align : center;color:black;font-size:30px;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="prestige10.html"> I care about a small undergraduate enrollment size. </a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="middle10.html"> The more the merrier.   </a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="college10.html"> It does not matter to me.  </a>
    </p>

This is pretty much the outline of what it the files contain. I want to make it so that if someone taking this quiz has picked mostly prestige, they will be recommended ivy league schools, middle will recommend average schools, and college will mainly recommend community colleges.
Thanks to anyone who can help me out!!-+

But you allready have a property that distiguishes each link - I mean, href property values are different for each link and lead to 3 different pages. You just need to create these pages and add content to them accordingly to users choice. Or maybe I'm wrong and you need something else?

As AnnaK said in the comments I don't think you need to store any sort of variable because the state is already stored by the page they're in.

If they pick prestige they will be directed to the prestige page.
If they pick middle they will be directed to the middle page.
If they pick college they will be directed to the college page.

Then these three pages might have their own links to the recommendations page with a url parameter specifying the chosen option.
Here's a mockup of the code
<!-- prestige10.html -->
<a href="/recommendation.html?chosen=prestige">See Recommendation</a>

<!-- middle10.html -->
<a href="/recommendation.html?chosen=middle">See Recommendation</a>

<!-- college10.html -->
<a href="/recommendation.html?chosen=college">See Recommendation</a>

<!-- recommendation.html -->
<p id="rec"></p>

<script>
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const chosen = urlParams.get("chosen");
const recommendation = document.getElementById("rec");
if (chosen == "prestige")
    recommendation.innerHTML = "a";
else if (chosen == "middle")
    recommendation.innerHTML = "b";
else if (chosen == "college")
    recommendation.innerHTML = "c";
</script>

